# AngularJS: service query returning zero result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

my `app.js` looks like

```
var app = angular.module('pennytracker', [
  '$strap.directives',
  'ngCookies',
  'categoryServices'
]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  console.log('configuring routes');
  $routeProvider
    .when('/summary', { templateUrl: '../static/partials/summary.html'})
    .when('/transactions', { templateUrl: '../static/partials/transaction.html', controller: 'AddTransactionController' })
});
```

while my `app/js/services/categories.js` looks like

```
angular.module('categoryServices', ['ngResource']).
  factory('Category', function($resource){
    return $resource(
      '/categories/:categoryId',
      {categoryId: '@uuid'}
    );
  });
```

and I have a route as

```
  .when('/transactions', { templateUrl: '../static/partials/transaction.html', controller: 'AddTransactionController' })
```

and my controller `app/js/controllers/transactionController.js` looks like

```
function AddTransactionController($scope, $http, $cookieStore, Category) {
 // some work here
  $scope.category = Category.query();
  console.log('all categories - ', $scope.category.length);
}
```

When I run my app, i see console.log as

```
all categories -  0
```

What is that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Category.query()` is asynchronous. It returns an empty array immediately and adds the result from the request later when the response arrives - from [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource):

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick
>   since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then
>   rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering,
>   once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated
>   with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the
>   new data.

If you need to access the result in your controller you should do it in the callback function like this:

```js
$scope.category = Category.query(function(){
  console.log('all categories - ', $scope.category.length);
});
```

Comment: geez :(,how come I missed that part in documentation. Thank you very much @joakimbi, it works now