# angularJS $resource response is both array AND object

Tags: json, angularjs

got this json file:

```
[
{
    "name": "paprika",
    "imgSrc": "img/paprika.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "kurkku",
    "imgSrc": "img/kurkku.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "porkkana",
    "imgSrc": "img/porkkana.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "lehtisalaatti",
    "imgSrc": "img/lehtisalaatti.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "parsakaali",
    "imgSrc": "img/parsakaali.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "sipula",
    "imgSrc": "img/sipuli.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "peruna",
    "imgSrc": "img/peruna.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "soijapapu",
    "imgSrc": "img/soijapapu.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "pinaatti",
    "imgSrc": "img/pinaatti.jpg"
}
]
```

Which I successfully fetch in a factory:

```
factory('getJson', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('json/vegs.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}
    });
  }]);
```

in my Controller I can get the json's file content:

```
var vegs = getJson.query();
    $scope.vegs = vegs;
    console.log(vegs)
    console.log(typeof vegs)
```

The weird part is the first console.log produces an array of objects, as expected.
The second console says it's an "object", and not an array.

I can get the .json content to my view using {{vegs}}, and I can use ng-repeat as well, tho in the controller I can't do vegs[0] or vegs.length. It comes out empty.

I'm breaking my head on this for over 3 hours now :)

Comment: It comes out empty b/c you're accessing the array before the server has responded. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18222998/398606)...

Comment: Actually that answer describes the problem, but doesn't seem to give a proper answer (you should not use `$scope.$watch`, instead use the `$promise` property or [pass in call backs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16389582/398606).

Comment: Read the answer that I linked to in my second comment :) In that case they have a resource named "Category" and when they call the `query()` function they pass in callback that will be executed when the server responds successfully.

Comment: Works! 
Can't seem to credit your comment tho :)

Comment: This is actually a common problem, and I was too lazy to type an actual answer so I really don't deserve any credit... You might up vote the answer that I linked to instead :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an 'answer'. Just an observation on one part of your issue. (Sorry, can't comment yet...new to stackoverflow).

Just a note on your comment that "The second console says it's an "object", and not an array." Using `typeof` on an array will always return `"object"`.

There are various (and debated, it seems) ways to test if it's an array--`Array.isArray(obj)` for example.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray